# Atom Appears in Section T1 Rewrite all a to c

Tags: prolog

I can do it on the list, but I don't know what to do about the term.

The answer I want is as follows.

```
s_atoc(f(f(a)),X) 
 X=f(f(c)) 

s_atoc(f(f(b)),X)
 X=f(f(b)) 

alphabet(a).
alphabet(b).
%alphabet(c).

Tm(T) :- alphabet(T).
Tm(f(T)) :- Tm(T).

s_atoc(T,T) :- alphabet(T).
s_atoc(f(T1),f(T2)) :- Tm(T1),Tm(T2).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you want to replace all the terms 'a' to 'c' but keep the other terms unchanged. If that's what you mean, here is a way to do:

```
% Define our three terms
term(a).
term(b).
term(c).

% This predicate is true only if X unifies with c. In other words, replace(a,X) is only true if and only if X is c
replace(a, X) :- X = c.

% This predicate is true only if the given parameters are the same and different than a
replace(X, X) :- term(X), X \= a.

% This predicate is true only if all the a in T are replaced by c in X
replace(f(T), f(X)) :- replace(T, X).
```

And here it is !
If you give to your program `replace(f(f(a)), X).`, it will give you `X = f(f(c))`

If you give it `replace(f(f(b)), X).`, it returns `X = f(f(b))`

Comment: I am grateful for your kind help!